# Which TraceSource to use for .NET Remoting

Tags: .net, remoting, .net-remoting

Which TraceSource name should I listen to when I want to get the traces of .NET remoting (e.g. TcpServerChannel)?

Comment: If you decompile the classes in the relevant namespace with Reflector or the like you can search for "TraceSource". Last time I did this I found that a lot of the older and original namespaces in the framework don't use TraceSource at all. "System.ServiceModel" will get any WCF parts.

Comment: I tried System.ServiceModel:

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "C:\\System.ServiceModel.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

But it doesn't work. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: nothing that jumps out at me. you could try copy paste from MSDN's sample config sections in case it is a typo issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx

Comment: well, they have some typos too (as stated in the comments) :D
but even with these corrected it simply doesn't write any file...

Comment: Check to see if the acct that is running has right to that file/folder. Also check the windows event log to see if any exceptions were thrown related to the logging.

Comment: I tried various folders, and in the event log i can't find anything of interest for this issue.

Comment: Trying adding an error to the trace listener on purpose, that will help see if the trace is even being activated/written to. If nothing is writing to the trace then the type and switchValues aren't evaluated.  You may have the thing configed perfectly and no code is writing to trace. Also check to see if the TRACE constant is defined.